# How to use CORS in javascript to get response from Dialogflow (Api.Ai)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, dialogflow-es

Since last couple of hours when I try to connect api.ai using javascript I get the following error .

"Failed to load https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I try to send request to Api.AI using javascript by following way:-

const client = new ApiAi.ApiAiClient({
    accessToken: "*******************"
});
const promise = client.textRequest(query);
promise
   .then(handleResponse)
   .catch(handleError);

function handleResponse(serverResponse) {}

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser Extension for this problem.
[In chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)
If you use PostMan or other service except browser you don't see this error or you can use nginx proxy to get result.

Comment: Don't keep this extension turned on all the time. This kind of extension should only be used for development purpose. If you are not sure what CORS is, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I too have started facing this issue from few hours, it looks like people at DialogFlow have changed the CORS restrictions.

Right now, only solution is to use a middle `proxy server` / `cloud function` which will call the api.ai url on behalf of browser and send the result back to browser.

Found the issue and answer [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/issues/102).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling the API from the browser. It is not a great option here as anyone can see your access code.

You can try the following solutions:

1. Call the API from the back-end - not front-end.
2. Use fetch API and disable CORS.