# Dialogflow api suddenly begun returning CORS error

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow was setup correctly and was working fine for about a month. Today it suddenly begun returning this error:

```
Failed to load https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?lang=en&query=hi&sessionId=bgknzzf1q: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4001' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CORS in javascript to get response from Dialogflow (Api.Ai)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789961/how-to-use-cors-in-javascript-to-get-response-from-dialogflow-api-ai)

Answer (score 0):

A way to resolve this temporary is to use a proxy as a temporary solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Example:

```
ApiAiConstants.DEFAULT_BASE_URL = 
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.api.ai/v1/";
```

The downside is that authorization headers and other info are passed on the way and can be intercepted. See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/issues/102

Comment: try deleting the function and api gateway and redeploying. This helped me. I'll try to reach out AWS, as this is clearly some freaking bug